# Replace whitespace but only between limits php

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace whitespaces with another string using PHP.

**I do it as follows**:

```
$string = 'whatever text including some $text between delimiters$ and...';
$string_replaced = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '\:', $string);
```

But it replaces all the spaces in the string, which is very logic.

I only want the regex to apply between the `$` delimiters.

In the [official `preg_replace()` docs](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php), I do not find anything that might help.

So I guess I am missing some PHP feature that will allow this.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, it does. Accepted and upvoted. Thanks a lot for your great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to match all texts between `$` symbols with `'/\$[^$]*\$/'` and then replace 1+ whitespaces only inside these matched texts:

```
$string = 'whatever text including some $text between delimiters$ and...';
$string_replaced = preg_replace_callback('~\$[^$]*\$~', function($m) {
   return preg_replace('~\s+~u', ':', $m[0]);
}, $string);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/5nsp8)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a slicker regex for only one `preg_replace` but you can match between delimiters , replace spaces, and then replace in the string:

```
$string = 'whatever text including some $text between delimiters$ and...';
preg_match('/\$[^$]+\$/', $string, $matches);

foreach($matches as $match) {
    $replace = preg_replace('/\s+/', ':', $match);
    $string_replaced = preg_replace(preg_quote("/$match/"), $replace, $string);
}
```

This also allows for more than one delimited string in the string.

Comment: Sorry. I've been wrong. Your solution is working flawlessly. I've deleted my previous comment so there is no confusion about your solution. Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$string = 'whatever text including some $text between delimiters$ and...';
//get substring without space
$sub = str_replace(' ','',substr($string,strpos($string,'$'),-strpos(strrev($string),'$')));
//replace sub string with new one 
echo substr_replace($string,$sub,strpos($string,'$'),-strpos(strrev($string),'$'));
```

Comment: This won't work if there is more than one occurence of delimited text, for example `text $between delimiters$ and then $some more$ will fail`.